# y_train in fit function has not the right dimension

Tags: python, keras

I have created an artificial collection of dots in a certain pattern to run a 2D classifier. Therefore, I insert points e. g. (x1,x2) and name their right class (label 1 or label 2). Both the points x_train and y_train are put into a Keras layer model and finally, I run the Model.fit method.

```
# Assign returned data
x_train, y_train = separate_dots_from_dict(dots)
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, NUM_CLASSES)
print("Shapes (x, y):", x_train.shape, ",", y_train.shape)

# Classification
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES * 8, input_shape = (2, 1, 1), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES * 4, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'sgd',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 4, batch_size = 2)
```

Before, I have printed out my point conversion results which came out successfully of my separate_dots_from_dict() function and which I have converted with the to_categorical() method from the Keras package. My function ends with

```
return np.array(x_train).reshape(len(x_train), 2, 1, 1), np.array(y_train).reshape(len(y_train))
```

and in the following, I show you 5 fictional points that are finally generated right before the classification begins:

X

```
[[[[ 0.5]]

  [[ 0.8]]]


 [[[ 0.3]]

  [[ 0.6]]]


 [[[ 0.1]]

  [[-0.3]]]

[[[ 1.1]]

  [[-1.1]]]


 [[[-1.4]]

  [[-1.5]]]]
```

Y

```
[[1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

Y is y_train so it is the training target e. g. the labeling.
The format of x_train (X) might seem awkward but it is exactly what is famous considering the reshaping of the MNIST images which I just implemented here analogously.
Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Shapes (x, y): (34, 2, 1, 1) , (34, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 88, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 4, batch_size = 2)
  File "/home/scud3r1a/Conda/envs/numtenpy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 950, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/scud3r1a/Conda/envs/numtenpy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 787, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/scud3r1a/Conda/envs/numtenpy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 127, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (34, 2)
```

All solutions that I was able to find have the solution to just change the units in the last Dense layer. But first, that does not affect anything and second, I think it is true as it is.

The dimension error scales with the x_train shape.
What to do here?

Comment: Can you try `y_train = y_train.reshape(x_train.shape)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Dense` layer expects the input of dims `(input_dims, None)`, what you are sending dims of `3`, which should be only `1` as expected(correct format). **None** represent the `batch_size`, which need not to be defined.

Try this change in your model:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(2,-1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES * 8, input_dim=(2,), activation = 'relu')
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after transposing the vector after your reshape approach. So an additional .T was necessary but now, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your input shape is not correct. You most likely tried to rebuild a Conv model, right?
The problem that you have is that your input to the dense layer has 3 dimensions. But what you want is just one dimension with something like e.g 32 neurons. In order to achieve that you either have to reshape the x input, or insert a Flatten Layer at some point before the output layer.
Further during model development it could be helpful for you to print the model (model.summary() does this). There you get an overview and maybe a better idea on how it looks like.